# Chrome: How can I dyn_cast() JavaScript objects that are part of a window created by window.open()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, rust, wasm-bindgen

I am working on a Rust WASM library that works with the DOM. To simplify matters, let's assume that this library receives a Node as argument, determines its root node and appends a newly created div to that root node ([Link to repo with complete MRE including HTML/JS](https://github.com/EliasHolzmann/window-open-chrome-instanceof)):

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn append_div_to_document_containing(element: web_sys::HtmlElement) {
    console_error_panic_hook::set_once();

    let document = element
        .get_root_node()
        .dyn_into::<web_sys::HtmlDocument>()
        .expect("get_root_node() did not return Document");

    let div = document
        .create_element("div")
        .expect("create_element() failed");
    div.set_text_content(Some("Created by WASM"));

    document
        .body()
        .expect("root_node.body() returned null")
        .append_with_node_1(&div)
        .expect("Appending failed");
}
```

Additionally, I have created JavaScript that can run this function on either a div contained in the current window or a div contained in a new window created via `window.open`:

```html
<input type="button" id="div_here" value="Add div here">
<input type="button" id="div_window_open" value="Add div via window.open()">
<script type="module">
    import init, { append_div_to_document_containing } from './pkg/window_open_chrome_instanceof.js';
    
    window.onload = () => {
        async function run() {
            await init();
            function createDivsWithJsAndWasm(document) {
                let div = document.createElement("div");
                div.textContent = "Created by JS";
                document.body.append(div);
                append_div_to_document_containing(div);
            }
            
            document.querySelector("#div_here").addEventListener("click", () => {
                createDivsWithJsAndWasm(document);
            });
            document.querySelector("#div_window_open").addEventListener("click", () => {
                createDivsWithJsAndWasm(window.open("", "", "popup").document);
            });
        }
        
        run();
    };
</script>
```

Both cases work in Firefox. However, the `window.open()` case fails in Chrome:

```
window_open_chrome_instanceof.js:260 panicked at 'get_root_node() did not return Document: Node { obj: EventTarget { obj: Object { obj: JsValue(HTMLDocument) } } }', src/lib.rs:11:10

Stack:

Error
    at http://192.168.12.34:8000/pkg/window_open_chrome_instanceof.js:266:19
    at logError (http://192.168.12.34:8000/pkg/window_open_chrome_instanceof.js:189:18)
    at imports.wbg.__wbg_new_693216e109162396 (http://192.168.12.34:8000/pkg/window_open_chrome_instanceof.js:265:66)
    at console_error_panic_hook::Error::new::h04dcf1f78b1b65a5 (http://192.168.12.34:8000/pkg/window_open_chrome_instanceof_bg.wasm:wasm-function[433]:0x1577b)
    at console_error_panic_hook::hook_impl::haf0cbfc93cb83b73 (http://192.168.12.34:8000/pkg/window_open_chrome_instanceof_bg.wasm:wasm-function[43]:0x6e7a)
    at console_error_panic_hook::hook::hff46bfaa806ee83e (http://192.168.12.34:8000/pkg/window_open_chrome_instanceof_bg.wasm:wasm-function[483]:0x162ad)
    at core::ops::function::Fn::call::hd9fb438233d248fe (http://192.168.12.34:8000/pkg/window_open_chrome_instanceof_bg.wasm:wasm-function[406]:0x150dc)
    at std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::hf4c39fada27bd187 (http://192.168.12.34:8000/pkg/window_open_chrome_instanceof_bg.wasm:wasm-function[116]:0xc839)
    at std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}::he7338bd7a89ffcbb (http://192.168.12.34:8000/pkg/window_open_chrome_instanceof_bg.wasm:wasm-function[186]:0xfc2b)
    at std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace::h0ded0f05f9eb8d88 (http://192.168.12.34:8000/pkg/window_open_chrome_instanceof_bg.wasm:wasm-function[612]:0x175c5)
```

I assume this is because in Chrome, the document contained in the opened window is not `instanceof HTMLDocument`, but `instanceof new_window.HTMLDocument`:

```js
let new_window = window.open("", "", "popup")
console.log(new_window.document instanceof HTMLDocument);             // false in Chrome, true in Firefox
console.log(new_window.document instanceof new_window.HTMLDocument);  // true  in Chrome, true in Firefox
```

This isn't just a problem with the `document` object, but with every JavaScript object that is associated with the new window. For example, the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` of a canvas inside the new window is not `instanceof CanvasRenderingContext2D`, but `instanceof new_window.CanvasRenderingContext2D`. Even the window itself is not `instanceof Window`, but `instanceof new_window.Window`:

```js
let new_window = window.open("", "", "popup")
console.log(new_window instanceof Window);             // false in Chrome, true in Firefox
console.log(new_window instanceof new_window.Window);  // true  in Chrome, true in Firefox
```

---

An easy solution in this example would be to use `unchecked_into()` instead of `dyn_into()`. However, in my real code, there are multiple `dyn_into()` invocations that I would need to replace with `unchecked_into()`, and I don't like the idea of giving up type safety just for this edge case.

Is there any workaround that allows successful `dyn_into()` casts on JavaScript objects that are part of a window created via `window.open`?